Connecting Java Desktop applications to Firebase
I have a very basic Java desktop application. Firebase has no SDK to be used in desktop application, as I understood
. In some questions,restAPI is suggested but is there any other basic option to connect Java to Firebase. I am not concerned with security issues since this project is a term project with no real usage. So I need the most basic solution. Thanks in advance.
